# Usar == para un char

Tags: c#

Quiero ver si puedo hacer esto en una una linea. interseccion es una variable que puede contener diferentes variables (todas de tipo char) y quiero ver si una de estas es igual a M

```
bool Flor = false;
var interseccion = playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0]);

if (interseccion.Count() == 2 && interseccion.Any() == 'M')
{
    Flor = true;
}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar con palabras lo que buscas ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver si contiene el caracter **'M'**:

```
bool Flor = (interseccion.Count() == 2 && interseccion.Any(x => x.Contains('M')));
```

Tú **variable Flor** tendrá el valor booleano devuelto por la expresión del lado derecho del signo igual.

Para ver si es igual a **'M'**:

```
bool Flor = (interseccion.Count() == 2 && interseccion.Any(x => x == 'M'));
```

**Actualización**:

Atendiendo a tu nueva situación te recomiendo que conviertas el resultado obtenido al aplicar el **GroupBy** en una lista:

```
var interseccion = playerCards.GroupBy(card => card[0]).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

El **método GroupBy** devuelve un:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>
```

Donde **TKey** es la llave por la que se hizo el grupo, en tu caso **card[0]**, y **TSource** serían todos los elementos agrupados bajo tu llave, bien podrías considerar estos elementos como una lista que comparten la misma llave.

Después de aplicar el **GroupBy** haces uso del **método SelectMany** el cual te crea una lista a partir de la lista de cada grupo.

Ahora tú consulta podría quedar de esta forma:

```
bool Flor = interseccion.Where(x => x.Contains('M').Count() == 2;
```

Filtro todo lo que tiene el caracter **'M'** y verifico que el total de esos elementos filtrados sea igual a **2**.

**Actualización 2**:

Solo tú sabrás tú contexto pero para mí el **GroupBy** siempre fue innecesario, prueba lo siguiente:

```
bool Flor = playerCards.Count(p => p[0] == 'M') == 2;
```

Solo se cuentan los elementos que en su primera posición tengan el caracter **'M'**, por tanto la **variable Flor** será **true** si ese conteo es igual a **2**, caso contrario será **false**.

También prueba esto:

```
bool Flor = playerCards.Count() == 2 && playerCards.Any(p => p[0] == 'M');
```

La **variable Flor** será **true** si en **playerCards** hay dos elementos y al menos uno de ellos tiene el caracter **'M'** en la primera posición.

Comment: Tal vez no quedó claro, `Any` es una función *superior*, que recibe la condición que debe cumplir cualquiera de los elementos. Es típico en la programación funcional.

Comment: Pero al escribir eso (la de contiene M) me salta este error: error CS1929: 'IGrouping<char, string>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<char>(ParallelQuery<char>, char)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<char>'

Comment: @Teo yo creo que el group by no te hace falta, para mí está de más, prueba a quitarlo

Comment: No si porque si no salta el error: error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'MazoCartas.playerCards' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @Teo revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: ahora no me salta ningun error pero Flor siempre termina siendo false

Comment: @Teo revisa la actualización 2 que añadí a la respuesta

Comment: @Japv la actualizacion 2 esta mal.. el no dice que M tiene que ser igual a 2.. si no que su lista tiene que tener 2 items, y al menos uno tiene que ser M....

Comment: @gbianchi le añadí otra posible solución

Comment: Y aca es donde falla porque la pregunta esta tan incompleta que no se entiende.. si me pongo a hilar fino, su group by podria agrupar 150 items en 2 grupos, con lo cual el group by es necesario... aparte de eso, uno de los grupos tiene que empezar con M... yo dejaria de agregar cosas a la respuesta que confunde mas, y pediria un ejemplo muchisimo mas claro del problema...

Comment: @Japv Muchisimas gracias quedo re bien con la ultima actualizacion